# cc.Class.extend not respecting functions

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

When ever I run the code below in Cocos 2D HTML or with bindings it seems to not add any of my functions but will add my Variables.

So:

```
cc.Class.extend({
   init: function(isDancing){
   this.dancing = isDancing;
},
   age : 5,
   dance: function(){
       return this.dancing;
   }
});
```

becomes :

```
 function anonymous() {
   this._super=null;this.age=this.age;
 }
```

Which I will get a undefined error when I try to call, dance().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

constructor function is 'ctor'(not 'init')

```
var Klass = cc.Class.extend({
   ctor: function(isDancing){
   this.dancing = isDancing;
},
   age : 5,
   dance: function(){
       return this.dancing;
   }
});
```

undefined

```
var el = new Klass(22);
```

undefined

```
el.dance()
```

22